# C++ MFC - code execution failure without throwing runtime error on CDialog::OnSize event (GetWindowRect)

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to access control size properties inside a CDialog::OnSize event handler. Code compiles and runs, but seems to fail at GetWindowRect. No run time error is thrown that I can see, but the code including and following the GetWindowRect call silently fails to run.

I have ran in release and debug mode, with breakpoints in appropriate positions (which are not hit GetWindowRect). I have also used code that modifies some member variables following GetWindowRect as an additional test, which I can also see is not running.

```
virtual void CMainFormDialog::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy) 
{
    ....

    auto pOutputEdit = (CEdit*) GetDlgItem(CE_OutputEdit);

    CRect pOutputEditRect;

    // No code is executed following this statement... 

    pOutputEdit->GetWindowRect(&pOutputEditRect);

    ....
}
```

Is there something wrong with the way I'm trying to access properties of my CEdit control here, and why does it fail silently?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you verify that GelDlgItem doesn't return NULL?

Comment: Just checked, yes it does return NULL. I use the same code in the main dialog member functions without issue. What do I need to do differently inside the event handler?

Comment: OK, I see what's happening now. The first time the code is hit is when the UI is loaded. The control has not been initialised. Subsequent OnSize events run with pOutputEdit != NULL. Problem solved, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnSize is likely called as part of the creation of the dialog, at a point where `CE_OutputEdit`may not yet have been created. `CE_OutputEdit` is created and bound as part of `OnInitDialog`. Check the return value of GetDlgItem and only perform whatever you need to do when it returns non NULL.

If needed use a variable that's set to true after you call `CDialog::OnInitDialog` and done other necessary initialization. Then use this variable in `OnSize` to determine if you should do your processing. Regardless of this, you should still check the return value of `GetDlgItem`

Comment: Ugh, don't add a flag. Just check the return value of `GetDlgItem`. That's what you should be doing *anyway*.

Comment: Agree, I've updated my answer to better reflect that.